# What's the supportedOS GUID for Windows 10 Insider Preview 18956?

Tags: xml, windows, exe, manifest

I'm trying to make my executable installer work on Insider builds of Windows, i have all the ID's for other Windows versions but i haven't been able to find any ID for insider builds... (If there even is such a thing?)

Searched around google for a ID, asked support agent on Microsoft he had no idea. So now i'm here, worth a shot.

I expected it to work and open the application just like in normal versions of Windows but in insider preview the installed executable tries to start up and quickly closes.

Comment: Are you sure it is caused by not having the insider Id in the app manifest? Check if there is any trace of error in event viewer.

Comment: You are probably right, i'll check.

Answer (score 2):

There is just one GUID for all Windows 10 releases. Recent Windows 10 builds added a new `maxversiontested` manifest element but it is probably not going to help you.

The GUID actually unlocks features and disables compatibility stuff, it never stops apps from starting/running.

Adding a GUID is not going to stop application bugs that causes a crash. You should run your installer in a debugger and try to find the cause of the crash. If it is a 3rd-party installer then you should open a bug report with them.